# Difference between time columns in SQL

Tags: sql, db2, sas, rdbms

I am trying to calculate the difference between two time columns in SAS EG. I am writing an SQL query to do that. But I am getting incorrect answers. Here is my query:

---

```
select 
Time_DP, Time_AR, (Time_DP-time_AR) as timediff  from table1
-------
```

This is what I get

```
Time_DP    Time_AR    timediff
23:00:00   20:31:00    22900
00:53:00   23:59:00   -230600
```

These are just examples of two rows that I got. I am guessing that the he timdiff values are in seconds. If so, they should be `149*60` seconds for 1st row i.e. `8940`.

I also need this colum in `hh:mm format` i.e. `02:29`

I have tried using below mentioned functions and none of them worked:

```
--DATEDIFF(hour, Time_DP,time_AR ) AS timediff
(Error: Hour is not a column of an inserted table. SQL code = -206, SQL state=42703)

--TIMEDIFF(CAST( AS TIME), CAST(time_AR AS TIME)) AS TIMIFF
(Error: No function by the name timediff having compatible arguments was found in the current path. sql code=-440, sql state=42284)

--DATEADD(SECOND, - DATEDIFF(SECOND, time_AR, Time_DP),) as timediff,
(ERROR: Second is not a column of an inserted table, updated table or any table identified in a from clause.SQL code = -206, SQL state=42703)

--Convert(time(0),(Convert(datetime,Time_DP) - Convert(datetime,Time_AR)),8) as timediff
( ERROR: Datetime is not a column of an inserted table, updated table or any table identified in a from clause.SQL code = -206, SQL state=42703)

--DATEDIFF(HOUR,Time_AR,Time_DP) AS timediff
(ERROR: Hour is not a column of an inserted table, updated table or any table identified in a from clause.SQL code = -206, SQL state=42703)
```

Thanks

Comment: The erroneous **mysql** tag should be removed from this question. It should be replaced with a tag that refers to the _actual_ RDBMS that is being used (Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server, et al.)

Comment: Yes @spencer7593 is right and its not mysql and error messages are not mysql error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In DB2 the result of the subtraction of two `TIME` values is a *duration*, a `DECIMAL` in the form `HHMMSS`. So, subtracting '20:31:00' from '23:00:00' gives 22900, meaning 2 hours 29 minutes 00 seconds. Subtracting a later time '23:59:00' from an earlier time '00:53:00' obviously gives a negative value -230600.